# How To Prompt a New Page After Inserting Name?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I created a simple page of my app today. And, now I want to expand it.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!
    @IBAction func myButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        display.text = "Hi \(myTextField.text!)! What can I do for you 
today?"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

I want the app to prompt a new page after the user entered their name.

Comment: there are plenty of ways to do that, you can find the answer with a little googling.

Comment: Most of the ways are creating multiple view pages(I think that's what it's called). And, the user would have to manually click on a button to proceed to the next page. I want the page to automatically pops up after the user input their name in the textfield.

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Storyboards_in_Xcode_6     Perfect tutorial for your requirement.

Comment: It wasn't what I was expecting but your link helped. lol Thank you!

Comment: Apps can't really figure out by themselves when the user has 'finished' entering in their name. There has to be some sort of an event that the user must trigger to indicate that he/she is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can conform to the `UITextViewDelegate` and present a viewController in `func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView)` like:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
   func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.present(/*the targeted view controller*/)
  }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what that means. lol But, I'll try plugging in the code everywhere and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: The user enters his/her name in the text field. If the textField's delegate is the view controller, and once the user is done editing (editing also includes typing in text into the text field), this method is called. By 'done editing', I mean that the user removes focus from the text field. But you still can't be sure that the user is actually done, so it's always safer to have a 'submit' sort of a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add target like

// In viewDidLoad

```
myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onNameChange(sender:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

// on value change

```
@objc func onNameChange(sender:UITextField) {
        // Do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I got your query as:

You want to go to new ViewController when the user is done with filling his name in the textfield.

If I got you right then choose the "**GO**" (or any thing you wish from options) as the Return Key value inside **'Text Input Traits Section' of Attribute Inspector**.

And now add this code in your view controller class with implementing UITextFieldDelegate:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool // called when 'return' key pressed. return false to ignore.
{
    print(textField.tag)
    if (textField.text?.isEmpty)! {
        //show alert that text field is empty
        return false
    }
     /* as per your case we have only one textfield,
        So there no need of switch case and you can 
        directly present your next vc from here without having any button on UI */

    return false
}
```